# Migrate only 2 sites from a site collection using content database approach

Tags: content-migration

I have 5 sites in a site collection.

If I want to migrate only 3 sites into my new environment, how can I do the migration using content database approach?

And

If I have 3 site collections in a web application and want to migrate only 1 site collection, how to migrate using content database approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can move the site collection to a new database and then migrate.

Start with creating a new content database from central administration.

- Application management > Manage content databases >  select "Add a
  content database" to the left > select correct web application and
  database server, select a name and click ok.
- Now you can move your site collections to the new content database
  using powershell.
- Open a new Powershell Window, be sure to run it as an administrator.
- Load the SharePoint snap-in using `add-pssnapin
  microsoft.sharepoint.powershell`
- Then use the cmldet Move-SPSite to move a site collection to another
  database. [Move-SPsite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915(v=office.15).aspx)

An example would be `Move-spsite http://webapplication/sites/sitecollection -DestinationDatabase "WSS_Content_NewDatabase`

- When you have moved the site collection(s) you need to perform an
  IISreset.
- After you have moved the number of desired site collections to a new
  database, you can do whatever you want. Take a backup, migrate, move
  to a test-environment etc.